# Sorting with parity in julia

Tags: julia

Suppose I have the following array:

```
[6,3,3,5,6],
```

Is there an already implemented way to sort the array and that returns also the number of permutations that it had to make the algorithm to sort it?

For instance, I have to move 3 times to the right with the 6 so it can be ordered, which would give me parity -1.

The general problem would be to order an arbitrary array (all integers, with repeated indexes!), and to know the parity performed by the algorithm to order the array.

Comment: Do you want the [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) (also called "sign") of the permutation, i.e., a single number,
or do you want a "parity" for each element of the array?
In the first case, once you have the permutation (`sortperm`), you can decompose it into a product of cycles,
and look at their length,
as in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65923/how-does-one-compute-the-sign-of-a-permutation) -- but if there are repeated values in the original array, the sign of the permutation is not well defined.

Comment: Yes, the parity is what I want. I think one can define exactly the parity with the rule that you have to do permutations of a number up to find it's equal. In the example that I gave, I wrote that the parity is 3, because exactly I want that the parity is well defined.

Answer (score 3):

If your array is small, you can compute the determinant of the permutation matrix

```
function permutation_sign_1(p)
  n = length(p)
  A = zeros(n,n)
  for i in 1:n
    A[i,p[i]] = 1
  end
  det(A)
end
```

In general, you can decompose the permutation as a product of cycles,
count the number of even cycles, and return its parity.

```
function permutation_sign_2(p)
  n = length(p)
  not_seen = Set{Int}(1:n)
  seen     = Set{Int}()
  cycles   = Array{Int,1}[]
  while ! isempty(not_seen)
    cycle = Int[]
    x = pop!( not_seen )
    while ! in(x, seen)
      push!( cycle, x )
      push!( seen,  x )
      x = p[x]
      pop!( not_seen, x, 0 )
    end
    push!( cycles, cycle )
  end
  cycle_lengths = map( length, cycles )
  even_cycles = filter( i -> i % 2 == 0, cycle_lengths )
  length( even_cycles ) % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1
end
```

The parity of a permutation can also be obtained from the
number of inversions.
It can be computed by slightly modifying the merge sort algorithm.
Since it is also used to compute Kendall's tau (check `less(corkendall)`),
there is already an implementation.

```
using StatsBase
function permutation_sign_3(p)
  x = copy(p)
  number_of_inversions = StatsBase.swaps!(x)
  number_of_inversions % 2 == 0 ? +1 : -1
end
```

On your example, those three functions give the same result:

```
x = [6,3,3,5,6]
p = sortperm(x)
permutation_sign_1( p )
permutation_sign_2( p )
permutation_sign_3( p )  # -1
```

Comment: The second algorithm here could be made quite a bit faster by not storing all the cycles, or even calculating the actual cycle, but just measuring the length of it and then adding one to a count `n_even_cycles` when it's even. Also, the third algorithm no longer works - there's no `StatsBase.swaps!`.

If you want I can replace the second algorithm with the faster version I've written.

Answer (score 2):

```
a=[6,3,3,5,6]
sortperm(a) - [ 1:size(a)[1] ]
```

Results in

```
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 1
 1
-3
 0
```

`sortperm` shows you where each n-th index should go into. We're using `1:size(a)[1]` to compare the earlier index to its original indexation.

Comment: Thank you for the reponse, I was also looking at `sortperm`. Perhaps the question is more complete now. The problem is to find the total number of permutations required to order a chain with repeated indexes.